# Como Incrementar Id con un INSERT en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla, y lo que quiero es crear una consulta que al insertar una fila, la consulta incremente el id desde la ultima fila que podría tener la tabla

Lo que intente hacer

```sql
INSERT INTO TB_USER(ID_USER,NOMBRE,APELLIDOS,CEDULA) 
VALUES((SELECT MAX(ID_USER) FROM TB_USER) + 1, 'NOMBRE', 'APELLIDOS', 'CEDULA');
```

La Consulta funciona, pero tiene un problema, cuando no existen registros en la tabla TB_USER LA COLUMNA DEL ID_USER, devuelve Null, y provoca un error y no se guardan los registros.
como puedo retornar 1 si no existen datos.
Espero haberme explicado lo mejor posible.
Gracias y espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Estimado las bases de datos SQL tienen una opción de crear un campo auto incrementable (auto increment), esto se realiza al momento de crear una tabla (o al modificarla). Luego cuando insertas un registro omites ese campo, ya que se agrega solo

Comment: Hola Muchas Gracias, si encontre en una pagina que se puede utilizar identity(1,1), pero sepodria hacer un incremento en un insert

Comment: mejorar el contenido de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

hola despues de intentos logre esto

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GUARDAR(
@INCREMENTO INT
)
AS
SET @INCREMENTO = (SELECT MAX(ID_USER) FROM TB_USER)
IF @INCREMENTO IS NULL

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TB_USER(ID_USER,NOMBRE,APELLIDOS,CEDULA,TELEFONO_1,TELEFONO_2,CELULAR,CORREO)
        VALUES (1,'Milton David', 'Gago Mercado', '25658545','9848998','8577689','4884448','correo');

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
          INSERT INTO TB_USER(ID_USER,NOMBRE,APELLIDOS,CEDULA,TELEFONO_1,TELEFONO_2,CELULAR,CORREO)
        VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID_USER) FROM TB_USER) + 1,'Milton David', 'Gago Mercado', '25658545','9848998','8577689','4884448','correo');

    END

GO
```

a mi me funciona

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona la consulta. Recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para ti, sino también para los demás que tengan un problema similar, que puede que no comprendan su funcionamiento. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

disculpa si no cumplo con alguna etiqueta

para el caso que planteas existen muchas soluciones, la de mas abajo es como lo tienes propuesto, pero no es escalable.

podrias tener una tabla con los modelos y el nro de secuencia disponible e ir incrementandolo luego de usarlo, con lo cual no tendrias huecos o gaps (poco escalable).

si solo lo usas como un campo clave (clave no natural) podrias usar un campo identity (el cual no agregas en el insert) donde debes saber que cualquier insert lo incrementara aun cuando falle o hagas un rollback de una transaccion, pero no tiene nada de malo tener huecos.

como otra solucion podrias usar un sequence, disponible en sql server desde la version 2012

```sql
drop table if exists #TB_USER
create table #TB_USER (ID_USER int not null , nombre Nvarchar(50), apellidos Nvarchar(50), cedula Nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO #TB_USER(ID_USER,NOMBRE,APELLIDOS,CEDULA) 
VALUES(isnull((SELECT MAX(ID_USER) FROM #TB_USER),0) + 1, 'NOMBRE', 'APELLIDOS', 'CEDULA');

select * from #TB_USER
```